# Electron cannot read property getName of undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I was following the Electron menu example at http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.5/api/menu/, however I receive the error

```
Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined
```

This is occurring at the point where `require('electron').app.getName();` is called.

When I open the dev tools and take a look I see that `require('electron')` appears to load correctly, but `require('electron').app` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're doing this in the main process, if so you might want to check if you have another `electron` module installed somewhere, as mentioned in the FAQ: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.6/docs/faq/electron-faq.md#requireelectronxxx-is-undefined

Comment: That's interesting.  I'm doing this from a renderer process as described in this Menu documentation https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/menu.md.  I notice the link you provide says electron.app can only be accessed from the main process, but in the menu documentation sample they appear to be using it in the renderer process.  This got me to the solution though.  I was able to access app in the renderer using `require('electron').remote.app.getName();` it appears there is a mistake in the documentation I was looking at.